# i'm using a pageview and its children are gridviews with dynamic length and this make the page laggy, is there a way to make it smoother?

Tags: flutter, user-interface

code below represents the way i implemented the page knowing that all that are in a listview with other elements on top.

```
Container(
  height : productsProvider.allproductsList.isNotEmpty &&
           allproductsList.length != 2 &&
           allproductsList.length != 1
           ? allproductsList.length % 2 == 0
           ? (allproductsList.length /2) *(260)
           : ((allproductsList.length /2) *(265)) +(265)
           : 300,
  child : PageView(
            children : <Widget> [
              for( i < categorieslist )
                 child : Container(
                   child : GridVew.count(
                     children[ // my list of products]
                     )
                  )
             ]
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `list of products` is too long, you may need to use builder function for lazy loading.

Here is the example for long list in `ListView`:
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists

Here is the document of `GridView.builder`: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView/GridView.builder.html

Comment: it's true that my list of products is long but am loading just part of it at first then the rest when scrolling down, but even with just few products i still get a high ms/frame when using that gridview inside of my pageview so dont know how this can be solved to make the app smoother.